# Git вернуть удаление кеша

Tags: git, gitignore

Добавил ненужную папку в `.gitignore` и хотел удалить кеш из `git status`, но прописал `git rm -r --cached .` Теперь боюсь что либо делать, подскажите, командой `git revert .` вернёт ли обратно кеш? Возможно нужна другая команда?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Добавил ненужную папку в `.gitignore` и хотел удалить кеш из `git status`, но прописал `git rm -r --cached .`

У вас теперь микс изменений - те что вы сделали разумно (и которые не хотелось бы терять, например изменения в `.gitignore`), и того, что сделали ошибочно через `git rm -r --cached .`.

В последней команде точка - текущий каталог. Вы очевидно были в корне проекта, и добавили в "stage" область (то что выводится `git status`) инструкцию на удаление из репо файлов. На диске в рабочем каталоге они, конечно, же остались.

Вот что нужно вам сделать:

```
git reset HEAD
```

Это "вернет" stage область (файлы затронуты не будут).

Вообще, удаление ненужных файлов лучше делать отдельным коммитом, не смешивая с полезными доработками - и нагляднее, и безопаснее. Вот так это делается:

Допустим, лишний каталог - это `error_log`, тогда:

```
git rm -r --cached error_log
```

Также вносим изменения в `.gitignore` и добавляем их в stage:

```
git add .gitignore
```

После чего - коммитим. На этом - все.

> Теперь боюсь что либо делать, подскажите, командой `git revert .` вернёт ли обратно кеш?

Нет. Эта команда нужна для отмены сделанного коммита. Так как вы еще не коммитили, она не нужна.

Comment: Даа, спасибоб большое! :)